# TikTok embed return 403 on some computers

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-403, oembed, tiktok

I am trying to create a web app that displays TikTok videos in it. In most computers, that works fine, but for one of the clients, the video is loaded but can not be played.
I get the following errors in the console:
[image: error messages]
(sorry about the bad image it is the best I got)

Notice that the URL returned `403` is `v16-web.tiktok.com` while I send the get request to tiktok.com.

This is the relevant code:

```
function embed_post(link) {
    fetch("https://www.tiktok.com/oembed?url=" + link)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            $("#post_view").html(data["html"])
        })
}
```

Where "link" is the link to the video in tiktok that looks like `www.tiktok.com/{user secUid}/{video id}`

Does anyone know how can I fix it?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: So maybe content is private and you must authorize?

Comment: Also learn how to make screenshots.

Comment: @Justinas This isn't something that happend for one video it happened on all videos (around 50) on the same computer and didn't happen at all on others.

Comment: @Justinas sorry, its not from my computer

Comment: Are  you sure the 'video is loaded' but cannot be played? 403 would hint at lack of permission from the server end.

Comment: @AHaworth I can see the first frame of the video with the play button link to the video on TikTok websit, but when trying to play nothing happend. I guess that despite the error, I get a partial data in the response.

Comment: @TomerShinar You see thumbnail of video, it's not same as video itself.

Comment: Since you can see the thumbnail, your request as shown in the code snippet seems to work if I understand you properly. When clicking on the play button, I guess, there'll be a second request to the url shown in the picture above.

Answer (score 2):

403 means the server side judged the authority of the media requesting and failed.
Cause the TikTok video load in a iframe, a possible reason is that the browser in those clients forbidden carrying cookies when requesting the media in a iframe (like in a Incognito mode).

Comment: Yes. For example, it happens in Chrome with default option of block 3rd party cookies. Might there be a workaround which doesn't imply enabling all cookies?